# setting custom attached property (reference type) in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

Context: I am implementing a system for attaching behaviors to objects*. It works as intended in code, but not in XAML.

**yes, I am aware of `Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.dll`*

In short, I want to be able to do this..

```
<Rectangle>
    <m:BehaviorExtensions.Behavior>
        <m:HoverBehavior />
    </m:BehaviorExtensions.Behavior>
</Rectangle>
```

..but seem to only be able to do this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <m:HoverBehavior x:Key="Hover" />
</Window.Resources>

<Rectangle m:BehaviorExtensions.Behavior="{DynamicResource Hover}" />
```

`m:BehaviorExtensions` does not [even] show up in Intellisense when I try to mark it up with nested tags like in the wishful example up top. What am I missing here?

This is the code defining the attached property:

```
public static class BehaviorExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BehaviorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Behavior", typeof(IBehavior), typeof(BehaviorExtensions), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, BehaviorChangedCallback));

    public static void SetBehavior(UIElement element, IBehavior behavior)
    {
        if (element == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("element"); }
        element.SetValue(BehaviorProperty, behavior);
    }

    public static IBehavior GetBehavior(UIElement element)
    {
        if (element == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("element"); }
        return (IBehavior)element.GetValue(BehaviorProperty);
    }

    private static void BehaviorChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IBehavior behavior;
        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            behavior = (IBehavior)e.OldValue;
            behavior.DetachFrom((UIElement)d);
        }
        if (e.NewValue == null) return;
        behavior = (IBehavior)e.NewValue;
        behavior.AttachTo((UIElement)d);
    }
}
```

Edit - Lesson learned:

Turns out this works just fine. It's Intellisense that needs to get with the program (literally). When I ignored it altogether and just typed what I wanted, things fell into place - i.e. compiled without a hiccup. When it comes to XAML, less respect for Intellisense is apparently what the doctor orders.

Comment: Looks legit. AFAIK any property can be written either as an attribute or as a nested element, the difference is purely syntactical. (Not all *values* can use the attribute syntax, though). What happens when you compile the program with XAML using nested tags?

Comment: You know what.. when I typed the nested tags with no regard to what  Intellisense regarded as contextually appropriate, it actually compiled and worked just fine..! Intellisense did its job (and rightfully served me m:BehaviorExtensions) when using the attribute syntax, so when it didn't in the nested element approach, I just figured I had made a mistake. I obviously have too much respect for Intellisense (plus I guess I'm fatigued after fighting XAML for a good while now trying to attach a *collection* property to the same end). Thanks for making me ignore Intellisense and test!

Comment: If the types you were referencing in your xaml had never been compiled (or were out of date), that could explain Intellisense freaking out.

Comment: No, the types had been compiled (and they are part of the same project). The first thing I do when this happens is a "clean/(re)build". This is similar to the error message "XX does not exist in namespace YY" that Visual Studio slaps you in the face with now and then when trying to reference your own types in XAML. The solution to THAT, I just discovered, is to *restart Visual Studio* and load up the project(s) again! Then everything works (provided it was actually correct to begin with).. That particular gem has cost me a LOT of frustration and time wasted hunting illusory bugs.